# Qual a melhor forma de adicionar um banner dinamico em outro site?

Tags: jquery, html, iframe

A situação é a seguinte, estou desenvolvendo um sistema onde os usuários podem criar banners dinamicos e personalizados com os nossos produtos e exibir em seus sites.
Os dados de cada banner criado ficam em nosso banco de dados. O que estou encontrando dificuldade é em exibir o banner no site de terceiros, não consigo pensar em um fluxo que não sobrecarregue meu servidor no caso de vários usuários possuírem sites com milhares de views ao dia.

Alguém tem alguma idéia?

Obrigado.

UPDATE:

A idéia é o cliente poder criar um banner, que vai rotacionar alguns produtos nossos(escolhidos por ele) em javascript(jquery). Porém toda a informação será puxada de nosso servidor, provavelmente utilizando ajax, para termos um controle sobre os banners exibidos. O que eu realmente queria era uma ajuda com esse fluxo, pois acho que essa não é a melhor solução, mas foi a melhor que consegui pensar até agora.

Answer (score 2):

**Esta é uma sugestão:**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

OpenX - um servidor de anúncios aberto para gerenciar a publicidade em sites e a entrega de campanhas de publicidade para os consumidores. Hoje é praticamente a única solução aberta disponível que pode ser instalado em seu próprio servidor e que atende às suas necessidades.

**Medidor de desempenho**

Antes de começar a otimizar sua instalação OpenX e em cada iteração melhorar a utilidade do sistema de captura de performance para entender o efeito é dado algumas alterações. Para fazer isso, os desenvolvedores OpenX recomendam o uso de Apache JMeter , onde você pode criar cenários de teste bastante complexas e obter estatísticas detalhadas sobre cada corrida durante a solicitação de teste. A documentação página do desenvolvedor OpenX tem um conjunto de scripts prontos para JMeter.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Arquitetura de servidor**

Aqui funções de interface de gerenciamento de campanhas e funções de processamento de dados estatísticos matérias apresentadas em um servidor separado, e de entrega são alocados para o número necessário de servidores, como é que eles têm a principal carga no sistema. Cada nó trabalha com seu próprio MySQL servidor de entrega, o clima na replicação de dados do servidor de banco de dados principal.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**SUGESTÃO DE ESTUDO:** http://blog.denivip.ru/index.php/2011/02/how-to-optimize-client-side-ad-loading/?lang=en

Comment: Isso está mais com cara de propaganda do que resposta.

Comment: É uma opção, amigo!

Comment: Obrigado pela dica, vou testar o revive-adserver que é a versão free open-source. Mas essa não era bem a resposta que eu estava procurando. Estou com vontade de codar mesmo.

Comment: Configurei o revive-adserver e não tme nada a ver com o que eu precisava. A idéia é o cliente poder criar um banner, que vai rotacionar alguns produtos nossos(escolhidos por ele) em javascript(jquery). Porém toda a informação será puxada de nosso servidor, provavelmente utilizando ajax, para termos um controle sobre os banners exibidos. O que eu realmente queria era uma ajuda com esse fluxo, pois acho que essa não é a melhor solução, mas foi a melhor que consegui pensar até agora.